# Asyncpg pool waits for all results

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, connection-pooling, asyncpg

I use asyncpg to make a heavy query that often takes around 15-20 seconds to compute. I was experimenting with a min and max sizes of a pool and noticed a strange behaviour. When I try to make multiple requests, they are executed simultaneously, but results return in a batch. The batch is always the same size as a pool. This behaviour leads to a long time of the first response, like 50 seconds or so. After a first batch, I need to wait for another 50 seconds, to get other results. It seems like asyncpg waits to collect all results from the pool and return them, rather than returning results as soon as they are ready.

Is there a way to get a result of a single request as soon as it executed? Maybe some setting that I'm missing?

For some time I could keep 25 connections, but it seems like a hack, which I really don't like.

I use DSN to create a pool if that's important.

```
db_pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(loop=self._loop, **params)
```

Here is the code, that I use to make a request to DB:

```
    async def first(self, query: str, values: List, db_name: str = 'default'):
        pool = self.get_pool(db_name)

        async with pool.acquire() as conn:
            return await conn.fetchrow(query, *values)
```

Right now I'm testing the default pool sizes (10 max, 10 min) and send 25 requests simultaneously.

```
result for 336997:  45.43796348571777 s
result for 368406:  45.43796348571777 s
result for 288307:  45.81912803649902 s
result for 283236:  46.499717235565186 s
result for 296000:  49.140310764312744 s
result for 304671:  49.20531177520752 s
result for 283685:  49.26837992668152 s
result for 283772:  49.3363881111145 s
result for 283720:  49.3753764629364 s
result for 294811:  49.39737892150879 s
result for 325604:  112.60201215744019 s
result for 336997:  112.60101222991943 s
result for 283028:  112.62509346008301 s
result for 291122:  113.41229104995728 s
result for 281105:  115.48561716079712 s
result for 304874:  115.59060764312744 s
result for 281875:  115.73372554779053 s
result for 283219:  115.73472547531128 s
result for 312094:  116.00303101539612 s
result for 312094:  116.0290174484253 s
result for 368406:  157.77449679374695 s
result for 325604:  157.77449679374695 s
result for 281932:  157.79654741287231 s
result for 290687:  157.79554748535156 s
result for 304874:  158.38678884506226 s
```

If I set max and min to 25, when I get these results:

```
result for 368406:  96.23042106628418 s
result for 368406:  96.22842144966125 s
result for 283236:  97.59920930862427 s
result for 304671:  99.69211030006409 s
result for 281932:  107.54676508903503 s
result for 283685:  107.95523738861084 s
result for 281875:  108.28549408912659 s
result for 283720:  108.39060115814209 s
result for 283028:  108.388601064682 s
result for 296000:  108.44459056854248 s
result for 283772:  108.55759739875793 s
result for 291122:  108.59360837936401 s
result for 294811:  108.90663266181946 s
result for 336997:  109.07162356376648 s
result for 325604:  109.07562470436096 s
result for 325604:  109.17762279510498 s
result for 336997:  109.30463767051697 s
result for 312094:  109.40563464164734 s
result for 312094:  109.40663456916809 s
result for 281105:  109.63970899581909 s
result for 290687:  109.66070008277893 s
result for 304874:  109.66170001029968 s
result for 288307:  109.68773555755615 s
result for 304874:  109.68273568153381 s
result for 283219:  109.68573522567749 s
```

5/5 connections bring terrible results

```
result for 288307:  38.87580060958862 s
result for 325604:  38.87280225753784 s
result for 283219:  38.87380290031433 s
result for 283772:  38.98385691642761 s
result for 304671:  39.80011057853699 s
result for 368406:  94.94180464744568 s
result for 283720:  94.94180464744568 s
result for 296000:  94.98080492019653 s
result for 294811:  95.45388603210449 s
result for 283685:  95.85135459899902 s
result for 291122:  156.6862394809723 s
result for 325604:  156.68523907661438 s
result for 336997:  156.68724012374878 s
result for 304874:  156.8772156238556 s
result for 283236:  157.72206735610962 s
result for 336997:  219.94082736968994 s
result for 368406:  219.96384191513062 s
result for 312094:  220.39882922172546 s
result for 281105:  220.8170771598816 s
result for 283028:  221.18352794647217 s
result for 290687:  283.105571269989 s
result for 281932:  283.10657024383545 s
result for 304874:  283.105571269989 s
result for 281875:  283.21556425094604 s
result for 312094:  283.7060844898224 s
```

Comment: How are you sending 25 requests simultaneously if you only have a maximum of 10 connections in one of your tests? At least some requests would have to be processed serially in that instance.

Comment: You understand that postgres spawns a process to serve the requests/quries from each connection, yes? So to execute 25 queries in parallel you *must* have 25 connections. You should also be concerned by the drop off in processing speed per query as you have more connections (from 40s/query with 5 conns to >100s/query with 25 conns). That suggests there is contention of some resource that is slowing processing. This will similarly effect any other concurrent queries against the database made by other applications.

Comment: @Dunes I understand that all 25 requests won't be processed simultaneously, if there are only 10 connections. I was wondering why the pool waits for results from all connections, rather than returning a result as soon as it is ready for 1 connection and start working on a new query, as soon as a connection becomes available? Why does it wait for other connections in the pool?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be waiting though. If you look at the pool of 10, the first 10 results return between 45 and 49 seconds. If it was batching the results I would expect to see those those times all within a 100 or so millisecond window. Perhaps there is some property of the query or dataset that means it has a fairly uniform processing time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue on the DB side, we had to increase resources to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Each query is only waiting for its own results.  If all the queries take about the same amount of work, then they all (of those that are actually running) finish after about the same amount of time.  And is not all that similar anyway, the spread from 45.4 to 49.4 is not trivial.  If it were somehow intentionally synchronizing them, you would think it would do a better job of it.

> For some time I could keep 25 connections, but it seems like a hack, which I really don't like.

What would you rather do instead?  Use a lower number?  A higher one?  A random number that changes from minute to minute?  You should put a limit on connection pool.  Why would 25 be a hack but some other number would not be?